# PasswordChangeView Doesn't Show Success Message in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have tried some different things on this PasswordChangeView but still couldnt show the right success message even with SuccessMessageMixin

The messages works but not after clicking submit button it shows message after you come back again to password change url and shows blank password change form with success message.

What i want to achive is i want to show message to user when he/she clicks after submit button.
Probably answer is pretty easy but i am newbie and don't know how to handle this error and success messages in forms for now.

Everything works Perfect Changes password and redirects after sleeping 1 second.

Thanks For all help.

```
class PasswordChange(SuccessMessageMixin,PasswordChangeView):
  model = User
  form_class = PasswordChangeForm
  template_name = "passwordchange.html"
  success_message = "Password Changed Successfully You will be redirected in 1 second"
  success_url = reverse_lazy("password_change_done")


class PasswordDone(PasswordChangeDoneView):
  template_name = "password_change_done.html"

  def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
    sleep(1)
    return redirect("posts")
  return super(PasswordDone,self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

FORM CODES

```
<body>
  {{ request.user }}
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p}}
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  {% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ 
     message }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
 {% endif %}
</body>
```

Comment: Is displaying the message(s) on the "posts" page an option?

Comment: if you mean show success message on posts page that will be good too. if you have a solution for that

Comment: Add this to your base template so that any messages you add are displayed on all pages https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages

Comment: ı have already added them forgot the put in stackoverflow

Comment: Add the messages section to the "posts" template, or ideally to a base template that all templates extend

Comment: Thanks @Iain Shelvington it showed in posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone its solved

I have moved

```
{% if messages %}
  <ul class="messages">
      {% for message in messages %}
      <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message 
       }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

To Posts Page and message is shown.